# Using route parameters with CGI?

Tags: apache, cgi

I'm converting an API using the Slim PHP framework to CGI. Slim handles route parameters very nicely (e.g. www.mysite.com/processorder/38929/w1?a1=test where 38929 and w1 are route parameters and includes additional GET parameters).

What is the correct or best way to do this? Do I need to configure httpd.conf to somehow convert the route parameters to POST parameters or additional GET parameters before it calls my CGI program?

I'm using the the CGIC C library at boutell.com as a starting point, if that matters.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Well I feel a little foolish. The answer was obvious if I had taken my head out of CGI for a second.

Since the site is served with Apache, I just needed to create an .htaccess file to convert the "route" parameters to GET parameters, including a QSA modifier to retain the original GET parameters in the URL (a1 in my example).

Comment: Are you planning to share and explain the relevant parts of your `.htaccess`?